# Validation of viewstate MAC failed ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, machinekey

I am receiving the error message below:

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

After lots of search, I found this document https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218

In Above document i found below section

> Appendix A: How to generate a machineKey element

In this section, there is a function which generate `<machineKey>`
but i don't know where to put this code in my application and how to call this function.

Comment: `<machinekey>` should be kept in `web.config` file

Answer (score 1):

Generate machine key using [link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/GenerateMachineKey/GenerateMachineKey.aspx)

```
<machineKey
validationKey="56AB7132992003EE87F74AE4D9675D65EED8018D3528C0B8874905B51940DEAF6B85F1D922D19AB8F69781B2326A2F978A064708822FD8C54ED74CADF8592E17"
decryptionKey="A69D80B92A16DFE1698DFE86D4CED630FA56D7C1661C8D05744449889B88E8DC"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

The `<machineKey>` should be put inside `<system.web>` section.

Follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx)

Comment: Put this code in web.config `<pages enableeventvalidation="false" viewstateencryptionmode="Never"></pages>` Follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx)